# Screenshot Feature on Windows Store App

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2013, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I am making an app for the windows store, and one section, 'Create' allows the user to drag images onto a background to create their own little scene (the app is aimed at kids). I'm adding a screenshot button so the user can save their work once they are done, and I have all the coding done, error free, but once I run it and press the screenshot button the app fails. Any advice or help is appreciated.

I get this message originating from the button once it fails:

An exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' 
occurred in  mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

```
   async void btnScreenshot_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var bitmap = await SaveScreenshotAsync(controlsGrid);

    }
    async Task<RenderTargetBitmap> SaveScreenshotAsync(FrameworkElement    uielement)
    {
        var file = await PickSaveImageAsync();

        return await SaveToFileAsync(uielement, file);
    }
    async Task<StorageFile> PickSaveImageAsync()
    {
        var filePicker = new FileSavePicker();
        filePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("Bitmap", new List<string>() { ".bmp" });
        filePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("JPEG format", new List<string>() { ".jpg" });
        filePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("Compuserve format", new List<string>() { ".gif" });
        filePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("Portable Network Graphics", new List<string>() { ".png" });
        filePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("Tagged Image File Format", new List<string>() { ".tif" });
        filePicker.DefaultFileExtension = ".jpg";
        filePicker.SuggestedFileName = "screenshot";
        filePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
        filePicker.SettingsIdentifier = "picture picker";
        filePicker.CommitButtonText = "Save picture";

        return await filePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();
    }
    async Task<RenderTargetBitmap> SaveToFileAsync(FrameworkElement uielement, StorageFile file)
    {
        if (file != null)
        {
            CachedFileManager.DeferUpdates(file);

            Guid encoderId = GetBitmapEncoder(file.FileType);

            try
            {
                using (var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
                {
                    return await CaptureToStreamAsync(uielement, stream, encoderId);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                DisplayMessage(ex.Message);
            }

            var status = await CachedFileManager.CompleteUpdatesAsync(file);
        }

        return null;
    }
    Guid GetBitmapEncoder(string fileType)
    {
        Guid encoderId = BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId;
        switch (fileType)
        {
            case ".bmp":
                encoderId = BitmapEncoder.BmpEncoderId;
                break;
            case ".gif":
                encoderId = BitmapEncoder.GifEncoderId;
                break;
            case ".png":
                encoderId = BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId;
                break;
            case ".tif":
                encoderId = BitmapEncoder.TiffEncoderId;
                break;
        }

        return encoderId;
    }
    async Task<RenderTargetBitmap> CaptureToStreamAsync(FrameworkElement uielement, IRandomAccessStream stream, Guid encoderId)
    {
        try
        {
            var renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
            await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(uielement);

            var pixels = await renderTargetBitmap.GetPixelsAsync();

            var logicalDpi = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().LogicalDpi;
            var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(encoderId, stream);
            encoder.SetPixelData(
                BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
                BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore,
                (uint)renderTargetBitmap.PixelWidth,
                (uint)renderTargetBitmap.PixelHeight,
                logicalDpi,
                logicalDpi,
                pixels.ToArray());

            await encoder.FlushAsync();

            return renderTargetBitmap;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            DisplayMessage(ex.Message);
        }

        return null;
    }
    async void DisplayMessage(string error)
    {
        var dialog = new MessageDialog(error);

        await dialog.ShowAsync();
    }
```

Comment: What line generates the error? Can you step through in the debugger and repro? Does this repro every time and on multiple systems? I copied your code into a blank app and it worked fine (no errors and screenshot.bmp was created as expected)

Comment: The error is at the button.

Comment: We wrote the code in a blank app and it worked fine.. but as soon as we added it too our main project, it runs then fails when we try use the screenshot function.

Comment: I got it working.. I added a try/catch to catch the exception that was failing and it works fine now. :)